# Android OS create custom ROM boot layer

Tags: android

I am an Android enthusiast. Currently I am developing some applications which is related to android OS. I need to customize my device like I need to install some applications like media player and calendar itself in ROM boot layer so that no one can install any other applications.I just don't know how to get into it. Suggestions? Comments? Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Consider visiting [the Android hacking & development forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=564) on xda to ask such kind of questions. I don't think you will get suitable answers around here